# Css | Inward facing box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

The effect I want to achieve is similar to a box shadow, but the darkest part of the box shadow is at the edge of the div, and the lightest part is closer to the center.

Basically a reversed box-shadow that points inwards. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that's what you're looking for but there is an `inset` property for box-shadow that display an inward shadow.